# how to use jquery function wrap

Tags: jquery

```
<div  data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-theme="b" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" id="filter" class="wrapcoll">
    <div  class="part"data-role="collapsible">
        <p>ZYRTEC</p>
        <p>CETIRIZINE</p>
        <p>10MG</p>
        <p>B/10</p>
        <p>
        En cas de prescription de ce medicament ant&#233;rieure &#224; la date du  13.03.2010, _il y'a lieu d'appliquer le tarif de r&#233;f&#233;rence suivant: 75.00DA. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there a jquery script to transform my 5000 div like this:

```
    <div  data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-theme="b" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" id="filter" class="wrapcoll">
    <div  class="part"data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>
            <span class="medic">ZYRTEC</span> 
            <span>
                <a class="gene ui-btn-right"  href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" dat-inset="true">generique</a>  
            </span>
        </h3>
        <p class="dci">CETIRIZINE</p>
        <p class="dose">10MG                          MG</p>
        <p class="cond">B/10</p>
        <p class="desc">
        En cas de prescription de ce medicament ant&#233;rieure &#224; la date du  13.03.2010, _il y'a lieu d'appliquer le tarif de r&#233;f&#233;rence suivant: 75.00DA. 
        </p>  
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm not good on jquery i try wrap unwrap and add class fonction but did not do it and the result applyed only on the first div and i want it for all my 5000 div. thx for help

Comment: 5000 divs to manipulate at once is not a good idea. cant you print them in wanted markup in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwra/) functions for that.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">Hello</div>
<div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Using .wrap(), we can insert an HTML structure around the inner  elements like so:

```
$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.part').each(function(){
    var text=$(this).find('p:eq(0)').text()
    $(this).find('p:eq(0)').remove()
    $(this).prepend('<h3><span class="medic">'+text+'</span>\ <span><a class="gene ui-btn-right"  href="#"  \
data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" dat-inset="true">generique</a>  \
</span></h3>')
    $(this).find('p:eq(0)').addClass('dci')
    $(this).find('p:eq(1)').addClass('dose')
    $(this).find('p:eq(2)').addClass('cond')
    $(this).find('p:eq(3)').addClass('desc')

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nCRh6/14/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

wrap:

```
$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

and
unwrap:

```
var pTags = $( "p" );
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  if ( pTags.parent().is( "div" ) ) {
    pTags.unwrap();
  } else {
    pTags.wrap( "<div></div>" );
  }
});
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)